# Options to \documentclass not being passed to packages

Tags: class-options

Page 17 in the `The LaTeX Companion` suggests all options to `\documentclass` are passed to packages as class options. However, when I include `margin=1in` in the `documentclass` option in an attempt to pass it into the `geometry` package, it did not work. LaTeX warns the option is grabbed by any packages. I think the problem might be the word **class options**. Then is it true that not all options defined in a package are class options? In other words, is it true that in the context of a package, regular options are not necessary class options and one have to do extra work to make a regular option a class option?

Comment: It's not exactly an option of geometry, I think, as it uses a system `key=value`.

Comment: The fact the `geometry` accepts key=value options indicates that it does not use the standard latex option handling code.

Comment: But for instance, `showframe` option, that not take any  values,  works in as option in the document class.

Comment: Package options defined using `\DeclareOption` should pick up the document class option, but `\DeclareOption*` won't (and, as the others have pointed out, the key=value options won't either as they're not defined using `\DeclareOption`).